# Why does this until modifier return nil?

Tags: ruby

With this IRB session:

```
words = []
#=> []
word||=""
#=> ""
words.push(word) until(word=gets.chomp)==""

#=> nil
words
#=> []
```

I thought that `word` is set to `""`, then overridden by the users input which was <kbd>enter</kbd>, resulting in `word` being set to `""` again.

What am I misunderstanding that results in `word` being `nil`?

Comment: `word` isn’t `nil`; try entering `word` at the prompt after that.

Comment: `word||="" # => true` in the third session cannot be reproduced. And even your result `word||="" # => ""` in the second session goes against that.

Comment: Think about it: `word` must be `""`, otherwise the `until` loop wouldn't have stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A language like ruby is composed of expressions. Each expression has a return value. The `until` keyword is a flow control tool that allows to execute an expression "until" certain condition is fulfilled. Seems like an expression of the form `statement until condition` returns `nil`, regardless of what `statement`'s return value is.

In this particular case, that `nil` you get has nothing to do with the value assigned to `ẁord`

Comment: It's like how `puts` always returns `nil` even if it does things. That's just how it works.

Comment: Yes, more or less. The difference is that `puts` is a method that can be overwritten to return something else, while `until` is a keyword  built into the language.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. What I mean is that the return value does not mean it didn't do anything. Some functions do tons of stuff and return `nil` to avoid clutter.

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop): _"Like a `while` loop, the result of an `until` loop is `nil` unless `break` is used."_